# Negative relative positioning firefox chrome compatibility

Tags: css, css-position, flexbox, margin

I can't figure out why the negative relative positioning in firefox and chrome are different.
I'm also not really sure Flexbox is the latest and work.
*e.g.*

On **firefox** works wit:

```
margin-right:-200px
```

On **Chrome** works with:

```
right:-200px
```

**the Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, you're applying `-webkit-box-sizing` to to the `.flex-item` being collapsed.

You need to also add this property for webkit browsers, like Chrome.

Try adding `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;` to .flex-item`

Without box-sizing applied, the padding will contribute to the box's width, attributing to the box still being within view after being moved -200px.

See the results: http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/54/